# How much should I worry about these moldy-looking growths?

Tags: soil, raised-beds, mold

I have a raised garden bed that has started to show what looks like mold or moss on the soil:

[image]

[image]

[This website](https://gardenerd.com/blog/sage-advice-blog/moldy-soil/#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CThe%20mold%20you%20see%2C%20although,grows%20in%20rich%20organic%20matter.) seems to think it's harmless, while [this one](https://www.puroclean.com/blog/what-is-white-mold-and-is-it-dangerous/) disagrees. And then there's the green stuff. How much should I worry about it?

Comment: that soil looks very wet - does the bed drain properly? the mould and and moss type growths are because of the wetness of the soil...

Comment: @Bamboo I thought so, but I guess not... It's a self-watering bed, so maybe that's part of the problem? Nowhere for the water to go?

Comment: If there's a lot of unplanted soil and any plants present are relatively small, most of the water is not being used up. Bigger plants use more water.... You need to find a way to correct that amount  of water it receives, or to sort out drainage